# Short description info

Tags: point, bigcommerce, bullet

How we add short description in the form of bullet points below the product title.
like this...[in this photo bullet points are below the title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHKdw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an unordered list to the product record, in the product description textarea.

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If you're using default Cornerstone (6.6.1 at the time of this comment), you will need to:

1. Set `theme_settings.show_product_details_tabs` to false.
2. Move `{{> components/products/description}}` into the correct spot in `templates/components/products/product-view.html`.